# Pagination and OOP

Tags: php, class, pagination

Some may say that this problem is more about semantics but I guess it doesn't matter anyway.

I'm not very good with explanations so let me get straigth to the example, here're the classes

```
class User {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    function __construct($id, $name){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Group {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $members;
    function __construct($id, $name){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function getMembers(){
        if(empty($this->members)){
            foreach(getMembersFromDataBase($this->id) as $member){
                $this->members[] = new User($member['id'], $member['name']);
            }
        }
        return $this->members;
    }
}
```

Very self-explanatory. The problem is, `$group->members` looks like it's supposed to hold all members of that group, however if the group has about 10000+ members, this may take up some space, with every member having their unique data like names, ids, about me's and such. And to take it one step further it is unspeakable for a browser to display that many results at once, or even at all. How can pagination be done in this scenario? If I pass `getMembers()` a variable then `$group->members` becomes kind of nonsense because it is going to hold a very small portion of the group's members and what good is that?

Also this goes not for just this example, what ever it may be, groups, news, feeds - everything that may return too many rows at once, how is it done in OOP?

Comment: Do you really need to initialize every member of the group (all 10000 of them)? Keeping just their IDs wouldnt consume that much resources

Comment: Unsure what your actual question is. But you are going to need to define a limit per page, then you have 2 queries... 1 to return the rows within the offset (current page) and limit (this would be your getMembers I guess) and one to count ALL rows, so you know how many pages there are

Comment: @GytisŠk well in the end they all need to be shown to the user browsing the site. Most likely nobody will ever scroll through that many users but I need to have it as functionality

Comment: @rjdown I know how to do it, I was asking how pros do it in PHP OOP in the real world, because the way I think of is not pretty

Comment: So what are you looking for? A complete code example? There's not really much to it

Comment: @rjdown an example would be good but I'm rather looking for an explanation on how people do it, obviously I need pagination but how is it realized in oop that is what I want to find out

Comment: getMembers() should take a start and count argument

Comment: @Dagon but then what if I build some server script that runs continuously and can afford to hold all those members in memory and I need to load them, I need to build another method for that. It doesn't seem very universal

Comment: the arguments would be optional, if empty (or NULL or how ever you like to do it), just get all

Comment: well ideally you would have a method specifically for pagination. it's not meant to be universal, OOP is not about using the same method for every single thing. it's about abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to imagine therefore when you would actually use `getMembers()`, unless it was for some internal operation like, what? Update subscriptions?

Well you might say that could be evoking a filter.

```
getMembersOwingSubscriptions($date);
```

You need to define what kind of filters you need to display to the users who will be looking at results in a browser.

```
getGroupMembersByRegion($region);
getGroupMembersPaged($start, $end);
```

These could then clearly map to their own sql statements, unless you foresee your classes doing computations that you cannot do in sql alone.

These might even be coming from specialized classes, perhaps then you find you have no use for getMembers();